# JIRA Core: Bug occurs when editing issue status

Tags: jira

Good Morning everyone,

We have a bug in our JIRA instance,at some point we can't change a specific issue status (Re-opened, closed ..) for an unknown reason , however we can change other ones status ! it's occurring more often and often and it affects the work in the team.

PS: all the troubleshooting and the health checks gave a negative result (everything works perfectly) even log analyzer came with no errors.

this is the error message that I get when the bug appears. Please any help guys !?

**Error message when editing issue status**

[image]

Comment: This is something that you need to raise it in Atlassian Support not Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message I assume you have a problem with database configuration (transaction timeout). If you are still within a supported period you can raise a [support ticket for atlassian](https://support.atlassian.com/contact/#/) and they will walk you step by step to fix the problem. If you want to look for the solution by yourself I suggest starting with this guide: [Connecting JIRA applications to a database](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/connecting-jira-applications-to-a-database-861253039.html). Based on your database server there are several Jira specific requirements that need to be met, follow the subpage for your database server and ensure all the configuration steps are executed. If the problem will still exist you need to verify that you have the database driver in the proper version and that your [database server version is supported](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/supported-platforms-938846830.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I already sent a ticket to the Jira support team and on the other hand I'm testing database configurations for the MySQL